# How can I convert a three-column gradient to two columns?

Tags: html, css, background, css-gradients

I'm trying to do a 50/50 vertical background. I am attempting to use background-gradient to accomplish this but it is splitting the background into thirds instead of in halves.

If I change the degrees to 90 it will split the screen in half horizontally but when changed to 180, it's either only splitting the top half of the screen or it's splitting the screen into thirds.  Could someone explain what is going on and how to fix it?

[image]

```css
  body {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(1, 91, 187, 1) 50%, rgba(254, 213, 0, 1) 50%);
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font: 100% Stencil;
  color: red;
  font-size: 4em;
}

caption {
  text-align: center;
  font: 100% Ink Free;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font: 100% Old English Text MT;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
}

td {
  font: 100% Lucida Calligraphy;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}

tr td:nth-child(1),
tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background: #33adff;
}

tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background: #c0e0f2;
```

```html
<h2>A Table of Animals, Plants, and Cars</h2>
<table>
  <caption>Here is My Second Table in HTML</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">&#128049;Animals&#128054;</th>
      <th scope="col">&#127794;Plants&#127795;</th>
      <th scope="col">&#128664;Cars&#128663;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cat</td>
      <td>Pine</td>
      <td>Chevrolet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dog</td>
      <td>Oak</td>
      <td>Ford</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rabbit</td>
      <td>Cedar</td>
      <td>Dodge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wolf</td>
      <td>Spruce</td>
      <td>Toyota</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `no-repeat` to your `background` property

```css
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(1,91,187,1) 50%, rgba(254,213,0,1) 50%) no-repeat;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It just removes the background from the bottom 3rd of the screen and turns it white.

Comment: @DocR because your `body`'s height isn't the height of page. Try add this rule to css `html {height: 100%;}` At this moment the height of `body` is depend on content

Comment: @DocR if you add this rule you will not need to adding `no-repeat` to your `background` property

Comment: @EzioMercer, Sorry, but  this is incorrect, simply `no-repeat` will not work, `background-attachement` is necessary. check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/xv82y5z6/

Comment: @James It is strange in codepen.io it works. Anyway you can just add `html {height: 100%;}` and it will work too

Comment: @DocR if you need fixed background and set 50/50 height of visible space then you must use @James's answer. But if you want of the 50/50 of whole web page then you must use `html {height: 100%;}`

Comment: @EzioMercer, it is not problem with `codepen.io`, it needs to use background-attachment, if you want  `50/50 of whole web page` , add `background-attachment:scroll` instead

Comment: @James then you will loose `background-attachment: fixed` feature and the background will not be 50/50 of whole page. [https://jsfiddle.net/xv82y5z6/](https://jsfiddle.net/xv82y5z6/) you can just add `background-attachment:scroll` and see result

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the desired effect you want to accomplish can be done with another aproach, using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors. Something like this:

```
.split-bg {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.split-bg::before,
.split-bg::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.split-bg::before {
    background-color: rgba(1,91,187,1);
}

.split-bg::after {
    background-color: rgba(254,213,0,1);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
   height: 100%
```

to your `background`.

With CSS `background-attachement`, you tell css to fix the body background.

Also a good practice is to add `height:100%` as well to make the body full height of the screen.

```css
  body {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(1, 91, 187, 1) 50%, rgba(254, 213, 0, 1) 50%);
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font: 100% Stencil;
  color: red;
  font-size: 4em;
}

caption {
  text-align: center;
  font: 100% Ink Free;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font: 100% Old English Text MT;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
}

td {
  font: 100% Lucida Calligraphy;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}

tr td:nth-child(1),
tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background: #33adff;
}

tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background: #c0e0f2;
```

```html
<h2>A Table of Animals, Plants, and Cars</h2>
<table>
  <caption>Here is My Second Table in HTML</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">&#128049;Animals&#128054;</th>
      <th scope="col">&#127794;Plants&#127795;</th>
      <th scope="col">&#128664;Cars&#128663;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cat</td>
      <td>Pine</td>
      <td>Chevrolet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dog</td>
      <td>Oak</td>
      <td>Ford</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rabbit</td>
      <td>Cedar</td>
      <td>Dodge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wolf</td>
      <td>Spruce</td>
      <td>Toyota</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: make `background:linear-garident` not `fixed`, but based on the content, use `background-attachement:scroll` instead

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(1, 91, 187, 1) 50%, rgba(254, 213, 0, 1) 50%);
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font: 100% Stencil;
  color: red;
  font-size: 4em;
}

caption {
  text-align: center;
  font: 100% Ink Free;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font: 100% Old English Text MT;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
}

td {
  font: 100% Lucida Calligraphy;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}

tr td:nth-child(1),
tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background: #33adff;
}

tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background: #c0e0f2;
```

```html
<h2>A Table of Animals, Plants, and Cars</h2>
<table>
  <caption>Here is My Second Table in HTML</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">&#128049;Animals&#128054;</th>
      <th scope="col">&#127794;Plants&#127795;</th>
      <th scope="col">&#128664;Cars&#128663;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cat</td>
      <td>Pine</td>
      <td>Chevrolet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dog</td>
      <td>Oak</td>
      <td>Ford</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rabbit</td>
      <td>Cedar</td>
      <td>Dodge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wolf</td>
      <td>Spruce</td>
      <td>Toyota</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, pay attention to broswer capability, Safari seems not support it as  @A Haworth suggested.

Comment: This may work sufficiently in practice, but just be aware that background-attachment: fixed can have problems in Safari  see https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks for the small tip, doesn't realize that safari doesn't support it before, has included in my answer, but I think OP has states that it works, then I don't think it is nessary to add an answer works for all broswer. Just add a note for others who like at it